# Describing nested queries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to know some information about the columns returned by the Select query.
I managed to solve the problem for simple select query like `SELECT * FROM table` as follow :

```
CREATE VIEW myView as SELECT * FROM table ;
DESCRIBE myView;
```

But I have problems with nested select like `SELECT T.name FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS T`
While creating views for nested is not possible .

Answer (score 0):

You can just run `describe` on the query:

```
DESCRIBE SELECT T.name FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS T
```

If you still want to created views of nested query, you can create 2 views. One for the inner query:

```
CREATE VIEW myViewInner as SELECT * FROM table
```

One for the main query:

```
CREATE VIEW myViewMain as SELECT name FROM myViewInner;
```

Comment: `DESCRIBE SELECT T.name FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS T`  
Doesn't give the answer i want .
I created views because of that.
`describe SELECT * FROM table` doesn't give the same result as 
`CREATE VIEW  myview as select * from table ; describe myview ; `